# IDLE Warning on Startup

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

What does this mean?

> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable. Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

Comment: Which version of Python and macOS are you using?

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  Go to the page and follow the instructions.  Search SO for `Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information` for previous posts about this and how to implement the upgrade properly.

Comment: It is only warning. `Tcl/Tk` is language used by `tkinter` (and `tkinter` is use by IDLE) It means it is new and not fully tested so it can still have some bugs.

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded and installed Tcl/Tk 8.6, but the error message is still there. Will it affect PyCharm Edu?